# How do i add the items to the listView so i will see them each two lines one under the other one?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RssNewsFeeder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int lastIndex;
        string readableRss;
        private List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");

            lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n")
                               .Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                               .ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(lines[i]);
            }
        }
```

When im using a breakpoint i see that lines contain 100 indexs.
For example in index 0 i have: פרשת אייל גולן : כך הודו הקטינות - ״שיקרנו״
Then in index 1 i have: Wed, 29 Jan 2014 06:01:56 +0200

Then again in index 2 i have: "Hello this is a text"
And in index 3 i see: Wed, 29 Jan 2014 06:01:56 +0200

Each index of text of line is have its own date and time.

So in the listView1 i want to see this indexs in a row from top to bottom in this format:

Hello everyone
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 06:01:56 +0200

Hi all
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 06:01:56 +0200

This is a test
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 06:01:56 +0200

This format.

How can i do it ? If im just using it the way i did it now adding the lines to the listView1 i see it like this:

[image]

How can i change it to the format i want ?

EDIT**

Tried this now:

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Message", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Date", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");

            lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n")
                               .Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                               .ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i += 2)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item.Text = lines[i];
                item.SubItems.Add(lines[i + 1]);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

Result like before:

[image]

Still not good.

EDIT**

This is the code im using now:

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Message", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Date", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");

        lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n")
                           .Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                           .ToList();
        StringBuilder strToAddToList = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            strToAddToList.Append(lines[i]);
            continue;
        }

        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            strToAddToList.Append(" ");
            strToAddToList.Append(lines[i]);
            listView1.Items.Add(strToAddToList.ToString());//You can replace this with your ListView.Add code
            strToAddToList.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Still not working as i wanted.

The format in the listView1 should be:

Text
Date and Time

Text
Date and Time

Text
Date and Time

And if one of the text lines is too long then it should split automatic to a new line:

Text
rest of the  here Text
Date and Time

But in fact i dont see the text only part of it it dosent look like lines in the listView1 but from side to side and i dont see the date and time for each text.

The format of the variable readableRss is:

תוכנית קרי : ירושלים המזרחית בירת פלסטין
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 09:45:52 +0200

הערבים קוראים לפגוע ב'סיבוב השערים' האמור להתקיים מחר
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 09:38:23 +0200

הסיטואציה בסוריה: עימותים צמודי גדר ברמה''ג
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 09:36:22 +0200

טורקיה: הצבא הטורקי חופר תעלות בעומק 4 מטרים לאורך הגבול הסורי באזור ''אלראעי''.
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 09:35:26 +0200

So maybe the variable lines is not needed and we can use directly with the string variable readableRss.

This is the format it should look like in listView1.

But i keep see it a mess like in the images i uploaded before.

This is an image of how the variable readableRss looks like and this is how it should look like in the listView1:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly then there is some text at index 0 and some date at index 1 and you want to concat them and add it to your list. Similarly for index 2 and 3 and so on.

I have tried to address your problem in the below code. See if it suits your need and let me know.

```
        //Dummy values for testing
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        lines.Add("Hello from text");
        lines.Add("Wed, 29 Jan 2014 06:01:56 +0200");
        lines.Add("Hello from text1");
        lines.Add("Wed, 29 Jan 2014 06:01:56 +0200");

        StringBuilder strToAddToList = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                strToAddToList.Append(lines[i]);
                continue;
            }

            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                strToAddToList.Append(" ");
                strToAddToList.Append(lines[i]);
                Console.WriteLine(strToAddToList);//You can replace this with your ListView.Items.Add code
                strToAddToList.Clear();
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:** You can add the text to listView in the following 2 ways (I have not compiled the code so please rectify any errors):

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = strToAddToList.ToString();
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

OR the way you did in your question

```
listView1.Items.Add(strToAddToList.ToString());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: samar how do i add the strToAddToList to the listView1 ? Instead this: Console.WriteLine(strToAddToList); im trying: listView1.Items.Add( but im getting error when putting strToLoadToList .

Comment: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Text.StringBuilder' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check and let me know.

Comment: samar update my question again. With the code but also added an image in the bottom now that show how the variable readableRss looks like when using breakpoint. The same i want it to look like in listView1. Still not working.

Comment: Why have you added these 2 lines of code? 
        listView1.Columns.Add("Message", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Date", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left); 
These are part of Selman22's answer, not mine. Please remove them and then try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two columns to your `ListView` like this:

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Message", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Date", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

Then change your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i+=2)
{
   ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
   item.Text= lines[i];
   item.SubItems.Add(lines[i+1]);
   listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Selman22 i tried your code and updated my question with the code i tried your code and the result still its not good.

Comment: try to change View property: `listView1.View = View.Details;`

Answer (score -1):

ListView1.Items.Add("List item text")